# move the entire column up by one row not affecting other columns in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select, row-number

much appreciate any help. I have a table named lifelong like presented below.

```py
       id           first_meal            last_meal
    0   1  2022-07-25 12:28:00  2022-07-25 20:06:00
    1   2  2022-07-26 13:12:00  2022-07-26 19:09:00
    2   3  2022-07-27 14:13:00  2022-07-27 20:13:00
    3   4  2022-07-28 15:10:00  2022-07-28 21:22:00
```

I expect an output like below (ideally to save it in another table) where the entire column 'first_meal' is shifted up by one row. So I lost 2022-07-25 12:28:00 from 'first_meal' and moved everything up. But 'last_meal' column is intact and 2022-07-25 20:06:00 is still in the first row

```py
 id           first_meal            last_meal
0   1  2022-07-26 13:12:00  2022-07-25 20:06:00
1   2  2022-07-27 14:13:00  2022-07-26 19:09:00
2   3  2022-07-28 15:10:00  2022-07-27 20:13:00
3   4                  NaN  2022-07-28 21:22:00
```

I tried this answer from a fellow stackoverflow member but it did not work unfortunately

> 

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY first_meal DESC) rn
    FROM lifelong
)

INSERT INTO newTable (id, first_meal, last_meal)
SELECT id, CASE WHEN rn > 1 THEN first_meal END, last_meal
FROM cte;
```

Comment: `select id, lag(first_meal) over (order by id) as first_meal, last_meal from lifelong`

Comment: WORKKKKKEEDDDD!!!! You literally made my day mate. Can you answer below with the same code so i vote and accept your answer as a solution?